# How do I set up a Flask request to change the color of an HTML button?

Tags: python, html, flask

I'm having difficulty understanding Flask requests. I'm using it to change the state of a HTML button once it's been clicked, essentially changing the color from black to yellow. But I'm struggling to find how to link the Python and the HTML.

Here's my Python so far:

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def homePage():

    pageType = 'Controller' 
    btn1 = True

    if request.form['value'] == 'on':
        print("yes")
        btn1 = True
    elif request.form['value'] == 'off':
        print("no")
        btn1 = False

    return render_template("index.html", pageType = pageType, btn1 = btn1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.debug = True
    app.run()
```

And then in my HTML Template:

```
<form method=post>
    {%  if btn1 == True  %}
        <button type=submit class="btn btn-default" value="on"><i class="fa fa-lightbulb-o fa-5x" style="color:yellow;"></i><br>Lamp</button>
    {% else %}
        <button type=submit class="btn btn-default" value="off"><i class="fa fa-lightbulb-o fa-5x"></i><br>Lamp</button>
    {%  endif  %}
</form>
```

I clearly have gone wrong, just not sure where or how to make this work...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All HTML form elements need a `name` attribute in order for their data to be sent when the form is submitted. Your template should be:

```
{% if btn1 %}
    <button type=submit class="btn btn-default" name="lamp" value="on">...
{% else %}
    <button type=submit class="btn btn-default" name="lamp" value="off">...
{% endif %}
```

And that name is what you use to access the value from the request:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    if request.form['lamp'] == 'on':
        btn1 = True
    elif request.form['value'] == 'off':
        btn1 = False
```

Comment: Ok thanks, so i've made those amendments, however it's now giving the error HTTP 400 Bad Request... Why would this be?

Comment: That happens when the request does not contain the data. That's probably occurring on the original GET of the page, which obviously doesn't contain the form submission data. Since you're handling both POST and GET in the same function, you'll need to check that you are actually in a POST before trying to get the value: see my update above.